# PCI-E RAID Card prevents boot (fans on, no display)

Tags: boot, motherboard, raid

RAID Card: LSI SAS 9240-8i (FW:P20 9211-8I IT Mode)

Computer: Intel DQ67OW, i7 2600K, 16GB RAM

Really peculiar fault... When I install the RAID card and start up the computer, I can hear the fans turn on at max speed but nothing else happens. No beeps, no blinks, just fans at max speed and no display on the monitor.

With the card removed, computer boots as expected.

Gone through pretty much every single setting on the BIOS with no luck.

I know that the PCI-E slot works because I had a GPU plugged in before I swapped it for the RAID Card (Only slot the RAID card will fit on this motherboard) and I know the integrated graphics work because I can boot into Windows without the RAID card plugged in. I actually bought two of these RAID cards (1 to use, 1 spare) and I see the same behaviour on both cards.

Have not seen this before and a bit puzzled, eventually I would like to turn this old computer into an Unraid box (hence the replacement of the GPU with this RAID card) but I am a bit stumped. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wild but covering pins 5 and 6 of the PCI-E connector with some kapton tape fixed the issue. System now boots and drives are picked up by Unraid.

Leaving this link here for a visual guide on how to do this: http://www.russellreeve.com/knowledgebase/H200/contents.html for future Google searches.

Comment: Link is now dead.  It's why people plead to put as much info in the answer as possible and avoid links.

Comment: Here is a link that is current.  I recommend updating your answer and using the pictures from this article and link it as source. http://yannickdekoeijer.blogspot.com/2012/04/modding-dell-perc-6-sas-raidcontroller.html

Answer (score 0):

Covering pins 5 and 6 of the PCI-E connector with some kapton (or electrical) tape fixed the issue. System now boots and drives are picked up by host OS.

As you can see on the picture below the tape applied. You must only cover these **2 pins on THIS side** of the controller, **do not tape the other side**.

[image: image of pins taped]

My edits were rejected on the original answer and their link is now broken.  I don't understand rejecting an edit that FIXES the original accepted answer that now has incorrect and incomplete data.  But, I was able to find [another source](http://yannickdekoeijer.blogspot.com/2012/04/modding-dell-perc-6-sas-raidcontroller.html) with pictures for those that like to have a bit of visual help.